# Having trouble getting google print to work within a C# application (403 Forbidden Error)

Tags: c#, printing, google-cloud-print

I am working on integrating google cloud print into a web application to allow clients to send pdf files to a printer after they are generated.

I've looked into all of the  documentation available on the google developer site and I have so far had no luck getting my test application to connect with the google print web services.

Here is the current process:

- Application gets permission from user and google to use/manage the user's printers (Using the google apis).
- This results in an 0Auth authentication token being returned from google.
- That token is used to create a new http request in order to attempt to create a new print job on the server (Not using apis as I couldn't see any avalible for this service).
- After posting the request, the application then attempts to read the response stream and.... 403 error, every time. Even though I'm certain I've followed google's header format to the letter.

So what I'm asking in a nutshell is:

- Are there any common trip ups when interacting with google web services like this which I may be making?
- Are there any apis available that would simplify the process of communicating with the google print web service.
- Are there any good alternatives to google print that I may want to consider.

Thanks.

```
private void SendPrintJob()
        {
            string googlePrintURL = @"https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit";

            Classes.pos_CloudPrintObject print = new Classes.pos_CloudPrintObject();

            print.printerid = "28a52678-43ef-6592-e32c-255e7220cb8a";
            print.title = "Test Print";
            print.populateTicket();
            print.content = "Hello World";

            //googlePrintURL += "?printerid=" + print.printerid;
            //googlePrintURL += "&title=" + print.title;
            //googlePrintURL += "&ticket={}&content=" + print.content;

            string queryString =
                "printerid=" + print.printerid +
                "&capabilities="  +
                "&contentType=" + "txt" +
                "&title=" + print.title +
                "&content=" + print.content;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit");
            request.Method = "POST";

            string code = Request["code"];

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + code);

            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "ASCII");

            //request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");

            request.Headers.Add("X-CloudPrint-Proxy", "TestProj");            

            request.ContentType = ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] bytePost = encoder.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(print));
            request.ContentLength = bytePost.Length;

            using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writeStream.Write(bytePost, 0, bytePost.Length);
            }

            HttpWebResponse response; 
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                //Prints out status of upload into debugger (But can be altered to return string instead)
                using (response)
                {
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            String result = reader.ReadToEnd();

                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + code);
```

to

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + code);
```

I hope , by **'code'** in the script means a valid token.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've just given this another try now and no dice. I'm still seeing the same error (403: forbidden). Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: did you have valid token. Please be noted that , the generated token will only be valid for one hour, after one hour you need to generate a new token..